# Python Speech-to-text program not registering microphone

Tags: python, text-to-speech, speech-to-text

So I'm creating this Python program where the user can verbally ask something and the program responds with an output. Think Jarvis from Iron Man. However, this is just the start of this project and it's nowhere near completed but it doesn't seem to want to pick up audio from my microphone. I've tested it in other software and it works fine but here it doesn't pick up anything and I get no error messages when I run the program.

```
import speech_recognition_python as Sr
import pyttsx3

"""
This sets a variable called Engine for the initialisation of the 
pyttsx3 library and
sets another variable for the chosen voice package I want to use 
within my program. The
activation word is also established as junior
"""

Engine = pyttsx3.init()
Voices = Engine.getProperty("voices")
Engine.setProperty("voice", Voices[0].id)
ActivationWord = "junior"

"""
This function allows the AI to take the given text and output it in 
the form of speech
"""

def speak(text):
    Engine.say(text)
    Engine.runAndWait()

"""
The parse function will give the AI access to the microphone and 
allow it to
listen for verbal inputs. It then establishes the microphone as the 
source of input
and allows for 5 seconds of silence before it times out. The 
user_speech variable is used
to store the audio coming from the microphone. The function will then 
pass this into googles
API service and store it as a variable named query. The AI can 
verbally output a sentence
if it doesn't understand the user's request. Finally the query is 
returned from the function
"""

def parse_command():
    speech = Sr.Recognizer()

    with Sr.Microphone() as source:
        speech.pause_threshold = 5
        user_speech = speech.listen(source)

    try:
        query = speech.recognize_google_cloud(user_speech, language = 
"en-in")

    except ValueError:
        speak("Sorry, could you please repeat that?")
        return "None"

    return query

"""
This is the main loop of the code where the AI will take the user's 
query and form an
appropriate response. The first thing it does is after the user says 
the activation word,
the AI will respond with a friendly greeting
"""

if __name__ == "__main__":

    while True:
        query = parse_command().lower().split()

        if query[0] == ActivationWord:
            query.pop(0)

            if query[0] == "junior":
                speak("Hello, how may I help?")
```

Comment: check how to format code properly so that we can copy and paste as opposed to screen copy it. use tripple ' ahead and after your code..

Comment: @JeJe I've done that now :)

Comment: please print the value of `Sr.Microphone()`.  Because you are calling this with no parameters, according to the [source code](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/8b07762f80dfec2d34fb4c40b8eddbb7ec503521/speech_recognition/__init__.py#L58) it should default to the system's default microphone.  What I suspect is happening here is that the `sample_rate` for the microphone needs to be explicitly set, as some microphones default to a higher sample rate than `PyAudio` is expecting.